# "equals error" in Sonar when using BaseEntity for JPA entities

Tags: java, jpa, sonarqube

We are using a BaseEntity class for JPA entites which implements equals method as follows.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (this == object) {
        return true;
    }

    if (object == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (getClass() != object.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

    BaseEntity other = (BaseEntity) object;
    if (this.getId() == null && other.getId() == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (this.getId() != other.getId() && (this.getId() == null || !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

For all classes which extends BaseEntity Sonar shows a code smell issue.

```
Override the "equals" method in this class.
```

[image]

How should we handle this?

Comment: You could disable this rule or override equals for all nested classes, calling `super.equals()` in each of them

Comment: But overriding in all classes might cause 'duplicated block' issue.

Comment: at-first, usually, duplication in equals means that your classes has the same fields and it's not really good. at-second, duplicated code you could extract to some util method

Comment: I mean if i implement equals in all classes extends BaseEntity and write only return super.equals() in all of them it will be duplicated code.. this is why i use BaseEntity. and implemented equals method is actually enough for me. But sonar is insisting on overriding equals. This is not right when using hibernate-jpa. Equality is based on 'id' in hibernate-jpa.

Comment: Was there any solution for this?